# Understanding Loss function and Learning Algorithm

Tags: keras, loss-function

In Keras, when specifying a loss such as Mean absolute error, does it replace the cost function in the learning algorithm (Adam or SGD) with the mean absolute error? I'm new to ML and a bit confused on this aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, They are the same. In machine learning models, the goal is to minimize the loss during training to compute the quantity that a machine learning model should seek. Depending on the type of data, we can use different loss functions.

[Here](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#binarycrossentropy-class) is the list of loss functions used in Keras. You can check how different loss functions work.

Comment: Okay, I just learnt that the Mean Absolute Error is not a compatible loss function with SGD, but it is with Adam, so I guess my question might be a bit confusing there.

Answer (score 1):

Learning Algorithm like SGD or Adam don't have any Loss/cost function associated with them. First You have to build a Model. Then pass the output of the model and target (Your labelled output) to the cost function.Then the cost function will compare the differences in output of target and model and also and calculate the gradient of loss function with respect to parameters.Then it is the optimizer like SGD that will use the gradient from previous step along with a learning rate to update the parameters of model. Cost function and Optimizer are two distince seperate things. You can basically use any cost function (even of your own) in combination with any optimizer.

It is easy to visualize like this:

```
MODEL ----> LOSS FUNCTION ----> OPTIMIZER
```

Comment: [link] (https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/general_concepts/gradient-optimization/) mentions that only the SSE and Logistic Cost functions are compatible with SGD, doesn't that mean I can't use MAE with SGD?

Comment: you have the freedom to choose any cost function and optimizer pair. But not all optimizer and cost function pair are good combinations. In the context of Deep Learning we rarely use MAE/MSE because the optimizers we use perform very poorly with MAE/MSE.So we use Cross Entropy Loss maximum time. The problem with MAE is that its gradient is not defined at zero. As SGD performs optimization based on gradient it can cause problem theoretically as we cannot compute gradient at origin. Although it is not a computational problem as the value will never reach absolute zero (a very small number)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm still a bit confused, does this mean that if I used a MAE loss with a  SGD optimizer - the model calculates the loss based on the MAE but optimizes the weights based on the SGD which uses the MSE? That's confusing.

Comment: No it will update the weights based on MAE. SGD doesn't have any embedded loss in it. You have to provide which loss function it should use and then it will use that function to compute loss and update the parameters.

Comment: Cool I got it now! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome. If my answer was satisfying ,don't forget to upvote. Thanks in advance